# Not able to get success in api response

Tags: ios, swift

This is how I am making an api request using URLSession:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.21.2/FeatureRequestComponent/FeatureRequestComponentAPI")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "AppID": "67B10F42-A372-4D4B-B630-5933E3F7FD65",
            "FeatureTitle": "ABCD",
            "UserName": "Ayaz",
            "UserEmail": self.userEmailTextfield.text ?? "",
            "Priority":"H",
            "Description": self.featureDescriptionTextView.text ?? "",
            "UseCase": self.useCaseTextView.text ?? "",
            "DeviceType" : "iPhone"
        ]
        request.httpBody = parameters.percentEscaped().data(using: .utf8)


        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data,
                let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                error == nil else {                                              // check for fundamental networking error
                    print("error", error ?? "Unknown error")
                    return
            }

            guard (200 ... 299) ~= response.statusCode else {                    // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 2xx, but is \(response.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
                return
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }

        task.resume()
```

}

```
 extension Dictionary {
        func percentEscaped() -> String {
            return map { (key, value) in
                let escapedKey = "\(key)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed) ?? ""
                let escapedValue = "\(value)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed) ?? ""
                return escapedKey + "=" + escapedValue
                }
                .joined(separator: "&")
        }
    }



    extension CharacterSet {
        static let urlQueryValueAllowed: CharacterSet = {
            let generalDelimitersToEncode = ":#[]@" // does not include "?" or "/" due to RFC 3986 - Section 3.4
            let subDelimitersToEncode = "!$&'()*+,;="

            var allowed = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
            allowed.remove(charactersIn: "\(generalDelimitersToEncode)\(subDelimitersToEncode)")
            return allowed
        }()
    }
```

above I have given the extensions for percent escaped and a character set also

But the response I get is an error like this:

```
responseString = Optional("{\"isError\":true,\"ErrorMessage\":\"Unknown Error Occured\",\"Result\":{},\"ErrorCode\":999}")
```

What am I doing wrong here...? I'm supposed to get a success in my response but what I'm getting is the error message.

Comment: You get proper response, so you should ask this to your web service developer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to detect the problem in your code but I did not find it

use my code war it works well

I hope this helps you

```
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: ["username":username,"password":password])

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://api.com/login")!)

request.httpMethod = "POST";
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpBody = jsonData

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
        return
    }
    let dataJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    if let responseJSON = dataJSON as? [String: Any] {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let User = responseJSON["user"] as! [String:Any]

            print("user: ", User)
            print("name: ", User["name"]!)
            print("email: ", User["email"]!)

        }

    }else {
        print("error")
    }
}
task.resume()
```